# Should static analysis tool compile code

Tags: c

Does there exist static analysis tool (C/C++) which analyzes code without being able to compile it?
(The reason I ask is my code may have some functions from external SDK)

Comment: Interesting question. A quick question, What kind of analysis a tool can provide if it does not try to validate(such as compile) your code? What kind of analysis do you expect the tool to do?

Comment: @PengZhang: It's not easy to answer. Maybe analyze only the functions and the usage of them in my code, signatures of which it knows. Since it doesn't know some function say `func1` from my SDK, probably it will not be able to check if I am using it correctly right? Since it doesn't know the signature of this function

Answer (score 6):

Most static analysis tools (e.g. [frama-C](http://frama-c.com/)) don't compile C code, but often requires its preprocessed form. So they require the availability of header files used by your code. Often, they fork the compiler just to get the preprocessed form (i.e. `gcc -C -E`)

<sup>Notice that these tools usually don't need or care about the binary form of the libraries you are using, only their header files.</sup>

However, I believe that extending a compiler to add much more static analysis abilities is a plus, since the analyzer can take advantage of all the work done (and the infrastructure provided) by the compiler. This is the main motivation for my (free software, obsolete in 2019) GCC MELT tool (which you can use to extend GCC to do some particular static analysis). Or the [bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon) framework (above GCC 11, which inspired the [RefPerSys](https://github.com/RefPerSys/RefPerSys) inference engine project)

Some few static analyzers -e.g. [coccinelle](http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/)- are able to handle unpreprocessed C code (using macros). But then, they need some way to understand the macros which your code is using (otherwise they cannot check much: a macro invocation can expand to many thousands statements!).

<sup>N.B. all the analyzers mentioned above are free software.</sup>

Comment: Yes that's what Flexelint asked online. Btw. I think CPPcheck doesn't require availability of headers

Comment: I think you can add CppCheck to that list (testing now, and I think it is analyzing code: http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

I have been using this for many years: [FlexeLint](http://www.gimpel.com/html/lintinfo.htm)

Comment: I think that's a good one. But can I use it online? (because it is not free). It has some demo: http://gimpel-online.com//cgi-bin/genPage.py?srcFile=semantics.c&cgiScript=analyseCode.py&title=Rule-based+semantics+%28C%29&intro=This+example+shows+how+FlexeLint%2FPC-lint+can+do+some+semantic+checking.&compilerOption=online32.lnt&includeOption={{quotedIncludeOption}}, can I use it from here? But once it was complaining about missing headers so I don't think I can use it with my code which contains functions from external SDK

Comment: Maybe splint is an option then.

Comment: @Igot: Why because it is free? Or because it can analyze code without compiling it?

Comment: It does not because it is a static analyzing tool.

Comment: Can I use FlexeLint online? Using link I supplied; Flexeling once refused to execute once it could not find header I included

Comment: FlexeLint is not free, you have to pay for it. In the link is just a small demo.

Comment: Yes but if I paste my code in it, it analyzes it also

Comment: As long as it suits you I have no complaints.